# Time complexity of 2 nested for loops

Tags: time, complexity-theory

This question is for revision from a past test paper
just wondering if i am doing it right

work out the time complexity T(n) of the following piece of code in terms of number of operations for a given integer n:

```
    for ( int i = 1; i < n*n*n; i *= n ) {
      for ( int j = 0; j < n; j += 2 ) {
         for ( int k = 1; k < n; k *= 3 ) {
         // constant number C of elementary operations
         }
       }
     }
```

so far i've come up with n^3 * n * log n = O( n^4 log n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your missing the key point. I don't see anywhere in the question it asking you to work out complexity in terms of Big-Oh. Instead its asking for number of operations for a given integer n.

Here is my solution,

For a given n, the inner loop variable successively takes the following
values: k = 1 ,3^0, 3, 3^2, . . . , 3^(m-1)

Therefore, the inner loop performs C log3n operations for each pair of values of the
variables j and i.

The middle loop variable j takes n=2 values,

And the outer loop variable i takes three values, 1, n, and n^2 for a given n.

Therefor the time complexity of the whole piece of code is equal to T(n) =
3C(n/2)log3n = 1.5Cnlog3n.

You may want to check this, but this is my interpretation of your question.

Comment: thanks for the help!, went back and looked at my notes and this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'll have a go.

The first loop is *O(1)* constant since it will always run 3 iterations (`1*n*n*n == n*n*n`).

```
for ( int i = 1; i < n*n*n; i *= n )
```

The second loop is *O(0.5n) = O(n)*.

```
for ( int j = 0; j < n; j += 2 )
```

The third loop is *O(log n)*.

```
for ( int k = 1; k < n; k *= 3 )
```

Therefore the time complexity of the algorithm is *O(n log n)*.